# Using model view presenter (MVP) in C# code

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, mvp

I'm a beginner to Model-View-Presenter pattern and I'm finding a way to use it in a sample application

In my C# winforms application has a `Employee Class` and it has properties like `EmployeeID`,`Name`, `Address`, `Designation` etc. Also it has behaviors like `viewEmployee()`, `AddNewEmployee()`, `PromoteEmployee()` etc.

1. Could you please suggest how these things are organized in MVP pattern?
2. I have several entity classes in my project like `Employee`, `Client`, `Attendance`, `Salary` etc. So should I make separate `DataService` and `Presenter` classes for each one?

My current understanding is like this...

```
Implementing ViewEmployee()----------

Class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}

Class EmployeePresenter
{
   public void ViewEmployee(string employeeID, frmEmployeeDetails _form)
   {
     Employee Emp= EmloyeeDataService.GetEmployeeData(employeeID);
     _form.txtName=Emp.Name;
     _form.txtAddress=Emp.Address;
     _form.txtDesignation=Emp.Designation;
   }
}

Class EmployeeDataService
{
    public static Employee GetEmployeeData(String employeeID)
    {
      //Get data from database
      // Set Properties of Employee
      //Return Employee
    }
}

Partial Class frmEmployeeDetails : Form
{
    btnViewEmployee_Click() //Button Event
    {
      EmployeePresenter.ViewEmployee(txtEmployeeID.text,this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think your question would be better if you fleshed it up with your actual working code, there's a lot of "placeholder" code in your post, which makes it border the line of off-topicness.
>
> You may be able to find more information and high-level design guidance about MVP on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

---

There isn't a lot to review here, but this is jumping at me:

```
public static Employee GetEmployeeData(String employeeID)
```

And then:

```
Employee Emp = EmloyeeDataService.GetEmployeeData(employeeID);
```

By doing that, you have *tightly coupled* the `EmployeePresenter` class to the `EmployeeDataService` class. The `static` method makes the `ViewEmployee` method harder to unit test - now whatever you do, if you call `ViewEmployee` you're going to call `EmloyeeDataService.GetEmployeeData`.

If you *code to an abstraction* instead of an implementation:

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    Employee GetById(string employeeId);
}

public class EmployeeDataService : IEmployeeRepository
{
    public Employee GetById(string employeeId)
    {
        // do whatever it takes to return an Employee object.
    }
}
```

Here you're accessing an SQL database with ADO.NET, but then later you might want to implement the same interface with Linq-to-SQL, or with Entity Framework - actually, the data could just as well be in XML files on the file system, or on Azure (cloud), or retrieved with some web service - all you need to care is the object's *interface*, which takes an `employeeId` and returns an `Employee`. Exactly *how* that's done, is irrelevant to the `Presenter`:

```
class EmployeePresenter
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _service;

    public EmployeePresenter(IEmployeeRepository service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

Now whoever is instantiating an `EmployeePresenter` will also need to instantiate some implementation of `IEmployeeRepository`, and *inject* that implementation into the presenter's constructor; you're no longer strongly coupled with a specific implementation, and you can change that anytime, without rewriting anything in the `EmployeePresenter` code.

---

This is more about SOLID and DI/IoC than MVP. I suggest you look at [this read from Martin Fowler about GUI architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html), there's a section on MVP.

However I can tell you that this isn't MVP:

```
partial class frmEmployeeDetails : Form
{
    btnViewEmployee_Click() //Button Event
    {
        EmployeePresenter.ViewEmployee(txtEmployeeID.text,this);
    }
}
```

The `Form` shouldn't know anything about a presenter, or any repository or service - it's just a *view*. Instead, you fire events that the presenter can listen to, and respond. Shortly put, the Hollywood Principle: *don't call them, they'll call you*.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by *view shouldn't know anything about a presenter, or any repository or service - it's just a view*? In your code `frmEmployeeDetails` does know about concrete implementation of presenter, `EmployeePresenter`. I dont think it violates any MVP or neat design principles.